# How to calculate the voltage and / or current in a crystal radio?

Tags: voltage, antenna, current-measurement, radio, field-strength

I have thought of using V=E*d for the voltage across the antenna (d being its length and E the electric field strength of the incoming radio wave) and then use I=V/Z with Z being the total impedance of the radio. Is that right?

Comment: Note that crystal diodes are *quite* nonlinear at the voltages in radios (unless you're next door to the antenna). Rather than a sharp "turn on" in the forward direction, there is a knee, https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Schottky-Barrier-Diode-Forward-Drop-versus-Breakdown-Voltage-for-4H-SiC-and-Diamond-of_fig1_232001386 . The curve is also temperature dependent: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Color-online-Forward-current-voltage-I-V-characteristics-of-diode-at-different_fig2_268524368 . This makes it hard to calculate actual output voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The monopole antenna of a crystal radio is regarded as "short". A "short" antenna is one that doesn't have a length corresponding with a quarter wavelength (an ideal monopole). It doesn't have a length of a quarter wavelength because it would be too big.

Consider a typical 1 MHz transmission. It has a wavelength of 300 metres and it would be nice to have a monopole antenna that is 75 metres long but it's impractical.

So we use a short antenna of typically 7.5 metres. This means that your formula for the length and electric field strength is a decent approximation. The formula gets more inaccurate as length approaches a quarter wavelength. But, as I've already mentioned this hardly can ever happen.

Regarding what the antenna produces at its terminals is a little more complex because, a short antenna is highly capacitive and the "wanted" signal has to pass through that impedance into our crystal radio circuit.

So, we usually tune out the capacitance with a coil and make the radio tuneable. This of course is a feature we desire so no problem here but, it does mean that we can't readily put a number on the voltage presenting itself to the diode detector.

> *How to calculate the voltage and / or current in a crystal radio?*

It's more dependant on your circuit coils and headphone impedance rather than what goes on with the antenna. You can of course model it in a simulator and maybe that's your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would you know any suitable simulator for what I want to do? By the way when you say "It's more dependent on your circuit coils and headphone impedance rather than what goes on with the antenna", are you implying that there is no way to find the current / voltage induced by the original signal (radio wave)?

Comment: Unless you are connecting the short monopole to a high impedance measuring device with extremely low equivalent input noise, you will never know what the pure antenna voltage is. You can calculate it as per your formula but, once you connect it to a crystal radio circuit it becomes highly amplified by the self capacitance of the antenna and the coils used for tuning. Of course you can calculate the Q of the resonant circuit at the particular part of the spectrum and make an estimate of the true antenna open circuit voltage.